# Puphpet, Vagrant and Nginx custom locations

Tags: linux, virtualbox, nginx, vagrant

I'm trying to add some custom Nginx locations to a Vagrant Puphpet config.yaml file and it seams I cannot find the correct format for that. I searched for it but no luck. Did anybody already did this and if yes, how?

This is how my config.yaml looks:

```
nginx:
install: '1'
settings:
    default_vhost: 1
    proxy_buffer_size: 128k
    proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
vhosts:
    www:
        server_name: 'www.localhost.com'
        www_root: /var/www/htdocs
        listen_port: '80'
        index_files:
            - index.html
            - index.htm
            - index.php
        envvars:
            - 'APP_ENV dev'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
location:
    vhost: 'www'
    location: '^/wiki'
    location_custom_cfg_prepend:
        - "root /var/www/htodcs/wiki;"
location:
    vhost: 'www'
    location: '/'
    location_custom_cfg_prepend:
        - "root /var/www/htdocs/main"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not natively supported in PuPHPet.

You can open a feature request ticket on the github repo, or submit a PR!